# Python: Slow algorithm with communities

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

I have two different community structure, but the nodes are the same. Both community structures are stored in a dictionary(key: name of community (string) ; value: nodes in this community (int list)) like this:

communities_map_friendship:

```
C0:[0, 20, 48, 55, 60, 68, 79, 81, 85, ...,  78190]  
C1:[1, 6, 10, 13, 18, 19, 22, 24, 26, ..., 78180]  
C2:[7, 21, 25, 29, 36, 37, 42, 49, 70, ..., 78146]  
C3:[40, 86, 103, 123, 129, 143, 154, 167, ..., 78172]  
C4:[66, 83, 133, 169, 174, 175, 205, 237, ..., 78166]  
C5:[179, 182, 188, 219, 228, 248, 265, 286, ..., 77981]
```

community_map_uservotes:

```
C0:[0, 20, 41, 48, 55, 60, 68, 79, 81, 85, ..., 78190]  
C1:[1, 6, 10, 13, 18, 19, 24, 26, 28, 30, 31, ..., 78173]  
C2:[22, 39, 43, 47, 53, 61, 69, 73, 97, 102, ..., 78180]  
C3:[7, 21, 25, 29, 36, 37, 42, 49, 70, 80, 83, ..., 78166]  
C4:[183, 483, 608, 1453, 2205, 2957, 3090, 3378, ..., 78149]
```

My goal is to count the cases when two different nodes are in on of the community lists in both structures. (e.g.: (0,20), (0,48), (20,48), ..., (1,6),(1,10),(6,10), ..., (7,21),...). It's important that is not required to be the same community. For example the nodes 7 and 21 are in C2 community in the first structure, but in C3 community in the second structure, but this pair should be included in the same way.

What I have already tried:

```
# Return true, if the two nodes are in the same community, otherwise return false

def Is_In_Same_Community(node1, node2, community_map):
    for community in community_map.values():
        if((node1 in community) and (node2 in community)):
            return True
        elif(((node1 in community) and (node2 not in community)) or ((node1 not in community) and (node2 in community))):
            return False
    return False

#The algorithm, which counts the appropriate value:

TP=0
for community in communities_map_friendship.values():
    res = [Is_In_Same_Community(x,y,communities_map_uservotes) 
          for i,x in enumerate(community) for j,y in enumerate(community) if i != j]
    TP = TP + res.count(True)
```

The algorithm is good, but the problem is that I have around 30.000 nodes, so it would run for days until I got the proper value.

Does anyone have an idea to speed up this algorithm somehow?

Comment: Did you use sets or lists for `node in community` check?

Comment: Are the lists guaranteed to be in order, as they appear in the example?

Comment: @Marat: I used lists for community check.

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes, the order is guaranteed!

Comment: @B.J switching to sets should speed up this code dramatically

Comment: Just to be clear…you intend to consider `(0, 20)` and `(20, 0)` as distinct?

Comment: @MarkMeyer No, (0, 20) and (20, 0) are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a different way to approach this. Consider two lists:

```
l1 = [0, 20, 48, 55]
l2 = [0, 20, 41, 48, 60]
```

The shared pairs between these lists are just the permutations (or combinations if you don't want (0, 20) and (20, 0) to be distinct) of the shared members. For example the intersection of these lists are:

```
set(l1) & set(l2)
# {0, 20, 48}
```

So the shared pairs are `(0, 20), (20, 0), (0, 48), (48, 0), (20, 48), (48, 20)`

If you only care about the count, then you don't even need to worry about figuring out those pairs because we know the number of pairs is determined by the formula:

```
(n!)/(n -2)!
```

With that in mind you can just take the product of the keys from each list and add the count of the permutations of shared nodes:

```
from itertools import product
import math

mf = {
  "C0":[0, 20, 48, 55],
  "C1":[1, 6, 10, 13],
  "C2":[7, 21, 25, 55],  
}
mu = {
   "C0":[0, 20, 41, 48, 60],
   "C1":[1, 6, 10, 13, 18],
   "C3":[7, 21, 25, 29],
}

TP = 0
for p1, p2 in product(mf.values(), mu.values()):
    num_common = len(set(p1) & set(p2))
    if num_common >= 2:
        TP += math.factorial(num_common)//math.factorial((num_common - 2))

print(TP) # 24
```

Which is the same answer you get with your code.

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't take days for 30000 nodes, and the while loop could still be optimized some:

```
def count_pairs( cm1, cm2 ):
    count = 0  
    for k,l1 in cm1.items():
        if k not in cm2:
            continue
        l2 = cm2[k]
        i1 = i2 = 0
        common = []
        while i1 < len(l1) and i2 < len(l2):
            v1 = l1[i1]
            v2 = l2[i2]
            if v1 < v2:
                i1 += 1
            elif v1 > v2:
                i2 += 1
            else:
                common.append(v1)
                i1 += 1
                i2 += 1
        count += len(common)*(len(common)+1)/2
    return count
```

Taking the latest version of the question into account:

```
def count_pairs( cm1, cm2 ):
    count = 0  
    for k,l1 in cm1.items():
        for k2,l2 in cm2.items():
            i1 = i2 = 0
            common = []
            while i1 < len(l1) and i2 < len(l2):
                v1 = l1[i1]
                v2 = l2[i2]
                if v1 < v2:
                    i1 += 1
                elif v1 > v2:
                    i2 += 1
                else:
                    common.append(v1)
                    i1 += 1
                    i2 += 1
            count += len(common)*(len(common)+1)/2
    return count
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but not the best, because it compares the C2 only with C2, so for example the (7,21) will be skipped even though these two vertices are in same community in both structure. (First in C2, second in C3),

Comment: Huh?  You specifically say you WANT to count pairs in the same community.  And you *include* (7,21) in your example output.